# Using CSS to reproduce image out of containing div effect

Tags: html, css

Basically, i have 2 divs.
I must reproduse the following effect.
The image must overflow the containing white div, just like in the image.
How can i do this using css?

Thank you in advance
I have tried by using making the image size bigger than the containing div, and putting overflow-y:visible and overflow-x:hidden, but the effect is that a scrollbar is added to the right of the div, and that's not what i want.
[image: what i must do]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it by defining `position:absolute` in your image then position it with `top` and `left` attributes.

Here, i have done and example to you: https://jsfiddle.net/hvkvf4px/

Don't forget to define `position:relative` on your outside div too (the one with white background)

Answer (score 1):

try this code bellow

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container{
                background: white;
                width: 400px;
                height:400px;
                margin:1px auto;
                margin-top: 40px;
                position: relative;
            }

            .content{
                width: 300px;
                height:500px;
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -40px;
                margin-left: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background: grey; margin-top: 100px;">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="img.png" class="content" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i'ts should work